# fetchall() returning [] after inserting

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python 3.9.

The program takes 3 inputs (`username`,`password` and `email`) and then hashes the password variable with sha256 and returns it as `result`.`username`,`password` and `email` get inserted into a table called `accounts`. It commits the changes and uses `cur.fetchall()` to print out the table.

```
import hashlib
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('users/accounts.db')

print("Sign Up.")
username = input("Input your username : ")
password = input("Input your password : ")
email = input("Input your email: ")

result = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8"))

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into accounts (username, password, email) values(?,?,?)",(username, str(result.digest()), email))
con.commit()

print(cur.fetchall())
con.close()
```

Comment: There's nothing to fetch. You can only fetch after `SELECT` queries.

Comment: Not answering your question, but I hope this isn't for production code.  Hashing passwords (even with SHA256) is a terrible way to store passwords.  At the minimum, you need to add "salt" to the password. Optimally, you should be using pbkdf2.

Comment: I know, Obviously this is not for production and I know about salts and pbkdf2, I just haven't implemented them. This is a test code. @Fra

Comment: @Gurseerit.  Okay.  Just double checking.  It's not completely obvious this wasn't for production code because this is pretty much what Adobe was using when their passwords were hacked, and why the breach was so serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a SELECT query first before you can fetch.